# Trying to create a heatmap for a planet wars bot which shows which army has the most influence

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, pydev

I'm trying to create a heatmap for a planetwars bot which indicates which influence a planet is under.
The initial map looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP0Fw.jpg

Ideally the Red planet should have a value of -1, the Blue planet should have a value of 1, and the planet marked 1 should have a value of 0. (Or 0 to 1, mean of 0.5 would work)

My initial analysis code is below, but the results it outputs are between 0.13 and 7.23.

```
for p in gameinfo.planets: #gameinfo.planets returns {pid:planet_object}
        planet = gameinfo.planets[p]
        own_value = 1
        for q in gameinfo.my_planets.values():
            if q != planet:
                q_value = q.num_ships / planet.distance_to(q)
                own_value = own_value + q_value

        enemy_value = 1
        for q in gameinfo.enemy_planets.values():
            if q != planet:
                q_value = q.num_ships / planet.distance_to(q)
                enemy_value = enemy_value + q_value

        self.heatmap[p] = own_value/enemy_value
```

I've also tried to add some code to curb the range from 0 to 1

```
highest = self.heatmap.keys()[0]
    lowest = self.heatmap.keys()[0]
    for p in gameinfo.planets.keys():
        if self.heatmap[p] > highest:
            highest = self.heatmap[p]
        elif self.heatmap[p] < lowest:
            lowest = self.heatmap[p]
    map_range = highest-lowest

    for p in gameinfo.planets.keys():
        self.heatmap[p] = self.heatmap[p]/map_range

    self.heatmap_mean = sum(self.heatmap.values(), 0.0) / len(self.heatmap)
```

The values ended up between 0 and 1, but the mean was 0.245? (Also the values actually ranged from 0.019 to 1.019).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved my problem, this is what the solution looks like.

```
#HEATMAP ANALYSIS
    for p in gameinfo.planets:

        ave_self_value = 0
        for q in gameinfo.my_planets:
            if q != p:
                ave_self_value = ave_self_value + (self.planet_distances[p][q] * gameinfo.planets[q].num_ships / self.own_strength)

        ave_enemy_value = 0
        for q in gameinfo.enemy_planets:
            if q != p:
                ave_enemy_value = ave_enemy_value + (self.planet_distances[p][q] * gameinfo.planets[q].num_ships / self.enemy_strength)

        self.heatmap[p] = ave_enemy_value - ave_self_value

    hmin, hmax = min(self.heatmap.values()), max(self.heatmap.values())

    for h in self.heatmap.keys():
        self.heatmap[h] = 2 * (self.heatmap[h] - hmin) / (hmax - hmin) - 1

    self.heatmap_mean = sum(self.heatmap.values(), 0.0) / len(self.heatmap)
    #END HEATMAP ANALYSIS
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: @AndrewKozak Still another 12 hours to go! Sigh.... 
New to actually posting in stack overflow. For the last year or so I've just used it as a resource, but not actually signed up to post. I'll make sure I mark it as an answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

```
for p in foo:
    ...
    ...
    for q in bar:
        ...
        if q != p:
            q_value = some_value / another_value
            own_value = own_value + q_value
```

Apologies for the gross simplification. Say `foo` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and bar is `[1, 5]`.

First time through, `p` is `1`. `q` takes `1`, so `q==p`. Next, `q` takes `5`, now `q!=p`, `own_value` accumulates the `q_value` which I presume is some positive number less than one.

But second time through, `p` is `2`. `q` takes `1`, so `q!=p`, so `own_value` goes up by some fraction of one. Then `q` takes `5`, so `q!=p` still, so `own_value` goes up by that same fraction again. This is where the problem lies: `(some_value / another_value) + (some_value / another_value)` breaks the -1 to 1 scale. You get 7.23 sometimes because that's how many times `q` did not equal `p`.

There is nothing in the

```
for x in foo:
    for y in bar:
```

construction that cares about normalising `for x in foo` - just `for q in bar`.

Comment: This explains what I'm doing wrong, unfortunately it doesn't help in how to do it right! :(